# Is there a way to connect Azure B2C using MSAL library in Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am able to connect to Azure B2C using AppAuth but that uses support libraries on Android. So I am looking for a way to connect to Azure B2C using MSAL 1.0.0 library. I don't see any clear solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal) which integrate Azure AD B2C into an Android App Using MSAL.

Code Snapshot

```
PublicClientApplication pApp = new PublicClientApplication(
                this.getApplicationContext(),
                Constants.CLIENT_ID,
                String.format(Constants.AUTHORITY, Constants.TENANT, Constants.SISU_POLICY));
pApp.acquireToken(getActivity(), scopes, getAuthInteractiveCallback());

// ...

authenticationResult.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Tony. This method has protected access in 1.0.0 version. Do you have any sample for msal 1.0.0 ?

Comment: When I use this method I get "com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: Sdk cancelled the auth flow as the app launched a new interactive auth request." error. What could be ther reason behind this error?

Comment: I got this fixed now by doing a bit of debugging in MSAL code. The issue was that in developer options, I had set "Don't keep activities" to true which was killing one of the Activity in MSAL library and thus it was giving above error.

Comment: @NikunjShroff then microsoft write their library wrong ... every app should work with "Don't keep..." because you never know when OS kill underlaing activity